# query certain part of value in datetime format

Tags: mysql, mssql-jdbc

I have a database column(time) which define the data type as datetime which is `2019-11-08 15:49:26.860`. I want to list out the data which belong to `2019-11-08` only regardless the timestamp. My database table will look like the following

```
ID | task | time  
1  | read | 2019-11-08 01:00:00.546
2  | sleep | 2019-11-08 03:00:00.546
3  | boxing | 2019-11-18 01:00:00.546
```

I tested the following query but it shown that the datetime is not the string value

```
select * from task where time = '2019-11-08%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `time` is of `datetime` datatype (which, by the way, is kind of counter-intuitive), don't use string functions. Use date functions instead:

```
select * from task where date(time) = '2019-11-08';
```

I would actually recommend using the following, since it is more index-friendly:

```
select * from task where where time >= '2019-11-08' and time < '2019-11-09';
```